# meet vs met and meets vs mets

Tags: past-tense, present-simple

I need help with grammar regarding plural of the "meet" vs "met" in 2 different contexts.

Following are 2 examples I'm struggling with, this is sample output of a program:

**Context 1:** check if installed software (existing program) is up to date

```
some requirement v2.8 >= v2.6 was met
some requirement v2.8 >= v2.6 was meet
```

I only suppose that the correct answer is "met" here

**Context 2:** check if installed software (existing program) is up to date

```
some requirement v2.8 meets >= v2.6
some requirement v2.8 mets >= v2.6
```

I have no clue for the second context.

Here `v2.8 >= v2.6` means that existing program must be version 2.6 or higher.
In both contexts the checking was made before output was generated.

Comment: The past tense form and past participle form of *to meet* don't mark number.  There is a "meet/meets" distinction, but there is no "mets".  What is the point of `v2.8 >= v2.6`? Are those software versions, or requirement versions, or even relevant comparisons in this context?  I can't make sense of the output no matter what form or placement the verb *to meet* takes.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I updated my question to be more clear. I would ask the question differently but then I may not have the answer I want.

Comment: I don't know how the question was worded before the edit; I would assume that there is some requirement that requires at least version 2.6 of some software, and something has checked the version of that software, determined that it is 2.8, and that it meets the requirement because (as it says) "v2.8 >= v2.6". I agree that there is no "mets"; a requirement was met, a version met the requirement, multiple requirements were met, and multiple versions met their requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In “X was met”, the word “met” is the -ed form of the irregular verb “meet”. This is the passive past tense.

The -ed form does not change based on the subject, so there is no plural “mets”, but the helper verb “be” does change:

- I was met
- You were met
- He/She/It was met
- We were met
- They were met

Comment: If I understand your answer, this means following: `v2.8 meets >= v2.6` and `v2.8 >= v2.6 was met` ?

Comment: Because we could also say `v2.8 >= v2.6 isn't meet` and `v2.8 >= v2.6 was met` This is why I find this so confusing.

Comment: @metablaster You are using the passive past tense here, which is always “was” or “were” + -ed verb. If you change or remove the was/were helper verb, the verb phrase will have a different tense with a different meaning.

Comment: @metablaster it might have been a typo, but note that you *can't* say "isn't meet", you'd say "isn't met" instead. This answer currently only explains for the past tense, but it's the same in the present tense: the helper verb "be" is what changes, not the word "met".